# Writing A Fish Shell Script With an Optional Argument

Tags: shell, fish

I have a fish shell script whose default behavior is to send an email when complete. I'd like to modify it to respond to a `nomail` argument from the command line. So, for example, running the script normally would produce an email:

`michaelmichael: ~/bin/myscript`

But if run with the `nomail` switch, it wouldn't send the confirmation email:

`michaelmichael: ~/bin/myscript nomail`

If I run the script with the `nomail` argument, it runs fine. Without `nomail`, `$argv` is undefined and it throws an error. I've scoured the fish shell documentation, but can't seem to find anything that will work. Here's what I have so far

```
switch $argv
  case nomail
    ## Perform normal script functions
  case ???
    ## Perform normal script functions
    mailx -s "Script Done!"
end
```

Running this throws the following error:

`switch: Expected exactly one argument, got 0`

Obviously it expects an argument, I just don't know the syntax for telling it to accept no arguments, or one if it exists.

I'm guessing this is pretty basic, but I just don't understand shell scripting very well.

Comment: It's more helpful if you post the specific error message.

Comment: added. sorry about that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wrap your `switch` statement like this:

```
if set -q argv
    ...
end
```

Also, I think your default case should be `case '*'`.

Comment: That worked (though `nomail` has to be the default case, not '*'). Here's what I changed it to: `if set -q argv; switch $argv; case nomail; echo Not sending mail.; case '*'; echo Unspecified switch.;   end; else; echo sending mail.; end`

Comment: @michaelmichael: By default case, I mean the default of the `switch` statement which is executed if none of the specified cases match. Exactly how you have the code in your comment. Sorry, I misread your original code and mistook "???" as if it were intended to be the `switch` default.

Answer (score 7):

If you prefer using switch statement it's also possible:

```
switch (echo $argv)
  case nomail
    ## Perform normal script functions
  case '*'
    ## Perform normal script functions
    mailx -s "Script Done!"
end
```